# Create ACF repeater field from front end

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a form users can use to post from the front end of a wordpress site.

I'm having trouble with creating repeater fields though. I've tried a couple of methods, but nothing seems to work:

```
$periods = $_POST['periods'];

    // for each perdiod, save the start/end date and notes
    for ($p = 1; $p <= $periods; $p++) {

        update_sub_field( array('date', $p, 'start-date'), $_POST['p'.$p.'-start-date'] );
        update_sub_field( array('date', $p, 'end-date'), $_POST['p'.$p.'-start-date'] );
        update_sub_field( array('date', $p, 'notes'), $_POST['p'.$p.'-start-date'] );

    } // end periods loop
```

and

```
    // for each perdiod, save the start/end date and notes
    for ($p = 1; $p <= $periods; $p++) {

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_'.$p.'_start-date', $_POST['p'.$p.'-start-date']);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_'.$p.'_end-date', $_POST['p'.$p.'-end-date']);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_'.$p.'_notes', $_POST['p'.$p.'-notes']);

    } // end periods loop
```

But these do nothing to the post itself.

The repeater is set up like this:

Date (repeater) ->

- start-date (field)
- end-date (field)
- notes (field)

There's also another repeater field in there (repeater within a repeater), but I want to get this one working first!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a post, you'll need to use the actual field keys for each field. You can't use the field name, because the db record hasn't yet been created. Check out Elliot's documentation [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/) for that info.

Here's how some code might look to do this:

```
$event_field_key = 'field_534d3f17f3ca2';

// for each perdiod, save the start/end date and notes
for ($p = 1; $p <= $periods; $p++) {

    $events[] = array(
        '_start-date'   => $_POST['p'.$p.'-start-date'],
        '_end-date'     => $_POST['p'.$p.'-end-date'],
        'date'          => $_POST['p'.$p.'-notes']
    );

} // end periods loop

update_field($event_field_key, $events, $post_id);
```

You will have to get the field key for that field in order for this to work correctly. To do that, go to your custom fields screen and look for screen options in the top right corner. Check the box that says show field keys. Your field keys should now show up to the right of the field name in the custom fields list. Use that to add the field.

[Here's Elliot's instructions](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/#finding-the%20field%20key) if mine didn't make sense.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Just a quick one, there is another repeater within the `date` repeater field. Would I just need to reference that field key like you've done here? Or would I have to do something different for a repeater within a repeater?

Comment: I've never tried that. I think you would just need to create another array inside of the events array for the second repeater. I don't believe you have a field key for sub-repeaters. I think you'll find that when you show the field keys, there isn't one for sub-fields.